# How to implement / do "Load more" or "See more" in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Still learning in Laravel Eloquent. I have no idea how to implement **Load more** or **See more** in view.

Here's my controller:

```
public function index(){
    $job = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()->paginate(3);
    return view('post.index', compact('job'));
}
```

Post.php

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',  
        'image',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

My desired view is liked this: [image]
Whenever I click the button **see more** the next record will append.

Somebody could help me how to this in proper & cleanest way.

Comment: I don't think chunk is the best thing for this. I would suggest using pagination instead.

Comment: @RossWilson Sir can  you help me in your pagination way. will appreciate.

Comment: Can you add your blade for javascript. Are you familiar with pagination by the way?

Comment: @RossWilson I'm using jQuery, ajax in my project Sir. As far as I understand in pagination, I need to add this "?page=2" in url to get the second data. But I have no idea how to append the data of page=2 to page=1

Comment: Ok, cool. I'll still need to see your blade and javascript code to be able to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @RossWilson suggested, you should use `paginate()` instead of `chunk()` (and note that `get()` becomes redundant):

`$jobs = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(3);`

Then, echo out `$jobs` in your 'post.index' view after looping over the jobs:

```
@foreach ($jobs as $job)
    <div class="job">{{ $job->name }} ...</div>
@endforeach

{{ $jobs }}
```

If you'd prefer only "Previous" and "Next" links to appear rather than page numbers, use `simplePaginate()` in place of `paginate()`. You can read more about this under "Simple Pagination" in Laravel's documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination

With pagination, Laravel will automatically append page numbers to the URL and update your query accordingly.

UPDATE:
Here is an approximate example of how you could load the next link results asynchronously with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var $posts = $("#posts");
  var $ul = $("ul.pagination");
  $ul.hide(); // Prevent the default Laravel paginator from showing, but we need the links...

  $(".see-more").click(function() {
      $.get($ul.find("a[rel='next']").attr("href"), function(response) {
           $posts.append(
               $(response).find("#posts").html()
           );
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. I got the simplePaginate. But can it be possible in "see more", I mean when you click "see more / load more" the next data will append?

Comment: I've updated the post with how I would approach this

Comment: Okey I will try Sir. wait.

Comment: Sir it stays only in page 2 when I click again

Comment: Perhaps slightly off topic but would you recommend this approach against a livewire package for Laravel?

Answer (score 6):

**The marked answer is closely correct. But I encountered a problem to that answer**, because it only stays at page 2, however I marked it as an answer because his idea really helpful.

So here's my customed answer. Credits to Sir @Sean Talbot the origin of my answer.

**My view:**

```
<div id="posts">
    @foreach($post AS $p)
        <p>{{ $p->name }}</p>
        <img src="{{ $p->image }}">
        <br>
    @endforeach
</div>

//specify the exact current URL inside [data-link] & dont forget to append "/post?="
<button class="see-more" data-page="2" data-link="localhost:8000/post?page=" data-div="#posts">See more</button>
```

**My script:**

```
$(".see-more").click(function() {
  $div = $($(this).data('div')); //div to append
  $link = $(this).data('link'); //current URL

  $page = $(this).data('page'); //get the next page #
  $href = $link + $page; //complete URL
  $.get($href, function(response) { //append data
    $html = $(response).find("#posts").html(); 
    $div.append($html);
  });

  $(this).data('page', (parseInt($page) + 1)); //update page #
});
```